# why does C code pauses after i give ./a.out?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
//This program is a sorting application that reads a sequence of numbers
//from a file and prints them on the screen . The reading from the file here,
//is a call back function . 

typedef int (*CompFunc)(const char* , const char* );
typedef int (*ReadCheck)(char nullcheck);
char array[100];
//Let this function be done in the library itself . It doesn't care as to
//where the compare function and how is it implemented . Meaning suppose
//the function wants to do sort in ascending order or in descending order
//then the changes have to be done by the client code in the "COMPARE" function
//who will be implementing the lib code . 
void ReadFile(FILE *fp,ReadCheck rc)
{
    char a;
    char d[100];
    int count = 0,count1=0;
    a=fgetc(fp);
    while(1 != (*rc)(a)) 
    {   if(a=='\0')
        {
        //d[count1]='\0';
        strcpy(&array[count],d);
        count=count+1;
        }
        else
        {

        d[count1]=a;
        count1=count1+1;

        }
    }   

}
void Bubblesort(char* array , int size , int elem_size , CompFunc cf)
{   int i,j;
    int *temp;
    for( i=0;i < size ;i++)
    {
        for ( j=0;j < size -1 ; j++)
        {
            // make the callback to the comparision function
            if(1 == (*cf)(array+j*elem_size,array+ (j+1)*elem_size))
                {
                    //interchanging of elements 
                    temp =  malloc(sizeof(int *) * elem_size);
                    memcpy(temp , array+j*elem_size,elem_size);
                    memcpy(array+j*elem_size,array+(j+1)*elem_size,elem_size);
                    memcpy(array + (j+1)*elem_size , temp , elem_size);
                    free(temp);
                }
        }
    }
}



//Let these functions be done at the client side 

int Compare(const char* el1 , const char* el2)
    {
        int element1 = *(int*)el1;
        int element2 = *(int*)el2;

        if(element1 < element2 )
            return -1;
        if(element1 > element2)
            return 1 ;
        return 0;
    }

int ReadChecked(char nullcheck)
    {
        if (nullcheck=='\n')
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    int k;
    fp1=fopen("readdata.txt","r");
    ReadFile(fp1,&ReadChecked);
    Bubblesort((char*)array,5,sizeof(array[0]),&Compare);
    printf("after sorting \n");
    for (k=0;k<5;k++)
    printf("%d",array[k]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where it gets stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Just perhaps the program is taking a little while to run... just perhaps.

Here's a possible issue: What happens when fgetc returns EOF (-1) ?

Comment: no it doesnt run it .. it doesnt terminate .. most probably an infinite loop

Comment: I don't think this is very time-critical... looking at the code, there seem to be only 5 elements to sort.

Answer (score 1):

`while(1 != (*rc)(a))`